# Comparing fields in select clause works in sqlite but not in DB2

Tags: sql, sqlite, db2, odbc

I'm checking for address discrepancies between two tables, using a query formed like this:

```
SELECT a.*, (a.address <> b.address) AS discrepancy 
FROM table1 AS a 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b 
ON a.uniqueIdentifier = b.uniqueIdentifier
```

What I'm expecting is that if a.address does not exactly match b.address, it will evaluate to true; hence the field, 'discrepancy' will return true or '1'.

(note, the left join is used because there may not be a matching row in table2, but I need to capture data from table1 regardless because I am iterating through the list and showing if the address has a problem)

The query worked in my unit testing with SQLite, but then failed in development with a DB2 database using ODBC.

The error code returned is `[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  [SQL0104] Token A was not valid. Valid tokens: (.`

If this is simply not supported in DB2, I'm open to alternate ideas how to craft the query.

---

Note: further testing shows that

`select a.id, (1+1) as two from table1 as a`

works, while

`select a.id, (1=1) as two from table1 as a` => `Token 1 was not valid`

Comment: You don't actually need the parentheses. Does it work without them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*, case when a.address <> b.address then 1 else 0 end AS discrepancy 
FROM table1 AS a 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b 
ON a.uniqueIdentifier = b.uniqueIdentifier
```

Answer (score 1):

DB2 SQL does not have a Boolean data type, so you cannot produce a Boolean value by an SQL statement. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT a.*,  
       CASE WHEN a.address <> b.address THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS discrepancy 
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why.  I googled db2 boolean and apparently boolean has been introduced in 9.7

Comment: Boolean data type can only be used in SQL PL programs, not SQL -- see [the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053651.html)